# Moving Focus From Terminal To File Tree

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to figure out how you can move the focus from the terminal over to the file tree. I am currently able to go from my code editing space over to the file tree with the snippet below:

```
{   // Toggle to the file tree
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "workbench.view.explorer"
    // "when": "viewContainer.workbench.view.explorer.enabled"
}
```

I am sure that it is an easy fix, but I am not certain how you can go about doing this as I am still relatively new to playing with the keybindings in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+e",          // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "workbench.explorer.fileView.focus",
  // "when": "terminalFocus"  // if you want it to work only when the terminal has focus
}
```

Comment: This did not seem to work for me. What happens when I am in the terminal and execute the key (I am on Mac) with my desired keybinding the terminal just executes whatever is in it. So if I had a `git pull` for instance then running the above keybinding would execute the terminal, not change the focus from said terminal to the file tree.